# Having trouble joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to write a query to display the name of each passenger with their fare.
Here's what I have so far -- it gives no errors, but also no results:

```
-- Write a query to display the Name of each passenger as well as the fare for their trip.
select passenger.name, departure_info.fare * passenger.quantity AS passenger_fare
from passenger, seat_passenger, manages, departure_info, seat_info
where departure_info.Dept_id=manages.Dept_id 
AND manages.Seat_id=seat_info.Seat_id 
AND seat_info.Seat_id=seat_passenger.Seat_id 
AND seat_passenger.Pass_id=passenger.pass_id
```

Here is the relationship view of the tables https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmhiJ.png

Comment: look into using implicit joins and start by joining one table at a time to make sure your joins are correct

Comment: Check if one your tables don't have records.

Answer (score 1):

using proper joins syntax will make this query from your query

```
select
    p.name, di.fare * p.quantity as passenger_fare
from passenger as p
   inner join seat_passenger as sp on sp.pass_id = p.pass_id
   inner join seat_info as si on si.seat_id = sp.seat_id
   inner join manages as m on m.seat_id = si.seat_id
   inner join departure_info as di on di.dept_it = m.dept_id
```

I suggest you to turn `inner joins` into `left outer joins` and see what you're missing

```
select
    p.name, di.fare * p.quantity as passenger_fare,
    sp.pass_id, si.seat_id, m.seat_id, di.dept_id
from passenger as p
   left outer join seat_passenger as sp on sp.pass_id = p.pass_id
   left outer join seat_info as si on si.seat_id = sp.seat_id
   left outer join manages as m on m.seat_id = si.seat_id
   left outer join departure_info as di on di.dept_it = m.dept_id
```

Actually, you could even remove unused joins (if you don't miss some records from seat_info):

```
select
    p.name, di.fare * p.quantity as passenger_fare
from passenger as p
   inner join seat_passenger as sp on sp.pass_id = p.pass_id
   inner join manages as m on m.seat_id = sp.seat_id
   inner join departure_info as di on di.dept_it = m.dept_id
```

Comment: Thanks. The query runs like it did before, just no results are showing up. I don't understand why. Here are the relationships in the database: http://prntscr.com/1jn80x I think it has something to do with that

Comment: Have you tried one with left outer joins? If it's not returning any row, it looks like your passenger table is empty

Comment: It's strange. Try to write select  * from passenger and then add joins one by one